# Power set's cardinality not always 2^n?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Math noob here, but hopefully this question is not completely insane.

I am confronted with two different rules about sets:

(1) Every set contains an empty set {}

(2) the cardinality of a power set is 2 to the power of the set's cardinality (i.e. 2^$Ā$ given a set $A$).

Given a set A = {1}, its power set is

$P(A)$ = {{}, {1}}

the cardinality of which is 2, which is in line with 2^$Ā$.

However, if we create the resulting set's power set, $P(P(A))$, it looks something like this:

$P(P(A))$ = {{}, {1}, {{}, {1}}}

the cardinality of which is 3. Given rule (2) above, I would have expected the cardinality to be 4.

The only way I could reconcile this is by saying $P(A)$ is really {{1}} (its empty set being only implicit), whose power set is then {{}, {1}}, the cardinality now being 2, which checks out. But suddenly it seems like power sets differ based on whether we explicitly include the empty set in the original set.

Simple oversight on my part or a deeper set theoretical truth?

Comment: Your powerset is incorrect.  It is missing $\{\{\}\}$ as an element.  Remember that the power set of $\{a,b\}$ is $\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.  Now, replace $a$ with $\{\}$ and $b$ with $\{1\}$.

Comment: you forgot to include the set containing the null set

Comment: Ooooh, so $P(P(A))$ should be {{}, {{}}, {{1}}, {{}, {1}}}?

Comment: It is worth mentioning also, it is more correct to say every set *has $\emptyset$ as a subset* and therefore every power set *contains $\emptyset$ as an element*.  It is ambiguous when you say the phrase "contains" and not specify whether you mean contain as a subset or contain as an element.  It is not true that every set contains $\emptyset$ as an element.  $\{1\}$ for example does not contain $\emptyset$ as an element.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much! In summary, turns out I was missing an empty set, and some curlies! :)